# Navigating to child route with route parameter in relation to current route - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to achieve this:

```
<button [routerLink]="['deepRoute', deepRouteId]">Deep Route</button>
```

But though an Angular `(click)` event, from any route (including child routes), like this:

```
<button (click)="navigateToDeepRoute(deepRouteId)">Deep Route</button>
```

Relevant routing code in my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'mainRoute',
  component: MainRouteComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'childRoute/:childRouteId',
      component: ChildRouteComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'deepRoute/:deepRouteId'
          component: DeepRouteComponent
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
....
```

**Given my routing**, I'm currently in the `ChildRouteComponent`:

`example.com/mainRoute/childRoute/1`

And would like to navigate to:

`example.com/mainRoute/childRoute/1/deepRoute/2`

Inside my `ChildRouteComponent`, I have my navigation method:

```
navigateToDeepRoute(deepRouteId) {
  this.router.navigate(['deeperPath', { deepRouteId: deepRouteId}, { relativeTo: this.route.parent } ]);
}
```

*But it's not working..*

I've also tried:

```
this.router.navigate(['deeperPath', { deepRouteId: deepRouteId } ], { relativeTo: this.route } );
```

And..

```
this.router.navigate(['../deeperPath', { deepRouteId: deepRouteId }, { relativeTo: this.route.parent } ]);
```

But still, no cigar. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, my issue had to do with a very minimal syntax error:

```
navigateToDeepRoute(deepRouteId) {
  this.router.navigate(['deeperPath', deepRouteId], { relativeTo: this.route } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
navigateToDeepRoute(deepRouteId) {
  this.router.navigate(['deeperPath', deepRouteId, { relativeTo: this.route } ]);
}
```

or

```
navigateToDeepRoute(deepRouteId) {
  this.router.navigate([`deeperPath/${deepRouteId}`, { relativeTo: this.route } ]);
}
```

You don't need to provide the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up trying your solution, but the `${  }` was throwing an error and asking jQuery to be used as an import. I ended up simply shortening my array to pass the path and parameter, excluding the route.

Comment: You don't need ${}, i have removed as it is a variable and value will be replaced. I have updated my answer.